# How to give NSAttributedString a Identifier?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to know, can I give `NSAttributedString` a `String` type of Identifier?

**like:**

```
AttributedString.Identifier = "AttributedString 1"
print(AttributedString.Identifier)
```

Then I get  **AttributedString** **Identifier** is `AttributedString 1`

**How to do this?**

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? You could wrap the string in a struct with members `value` and `identifier`.

Comment: Because I use NSTextAttachment.image to set a image.

Comment: And use NSAttributedString(attachment: ) to put the NSTextAttachment , Then I get a NSAttributedString with image.

Comment: But I need to know what  Identifier of this image , then I can use this Identifier to do thing.

Comment: Simply subclass it and add a property?

Comment: Thanks , I solved.